# How to Delete row of unbound data from dataGridView1?

Tags: c#, datagridview

i want to Delete row of unbound data from dataGridView1?
I made this code,

```
        private void deleteButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {

                dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);

        }
    }
```

But it's not working. Please suggest me some helping code. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Quite simple on IDE Mode. Just set **SelectionMode** of Datagridview at **FullRowSelect** property and on runtime just press Delete Key on Whichever selected Rows you want. and it will get deleted.

Or

Try some thing like below on button click event:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);

    }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think possibly you should not change collection of rows in dataGrid while enumerating it. You may firstly enumerate through dataGirdView1.SelectedRows collection to get rows to delete indexes, and then actually delete it. For example:

```
private void deleteButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // collect deleting row indexes
    List<int> deletingRowIndexes = new List<int>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
         deletingRowIndexes.Add(row.Index);
    }

    // sort indexes
    deletingRowIndexes.Sort();

    // remove rows in backward order to save rows indexes
    for(int i = deletingRowIndexes.Count - 1; i>=0; i--)
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(deletingRowIndexes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

code should work, try add `dataGridView1.Refresh();` after foreach loop.
I tested it and it works. `SelectedRows` is delete only selected Rows in DgridView

```
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ColumnA", "ColumnA");
     dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ColumnB", "ColumnB");

     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new[] {"1colA", "1colB"});
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new[] { "2colA", "2colB" });
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
     {

        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);

     }

     dataGridView1.Invalidate();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this....

```
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
            // invert row selections
            if (!row.Selected)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    row.Selected = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                row.Selected = false;
            }
        }

        // remove selected rows
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
  }
```